# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'IndexPath' - Xcode 8, Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I got error here after updating Xcode 8 and Converting my project to Swift 3

```
override open func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    guard let indexPath = indexPath else {
        return nil
    }
```

Message error :

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'IndexPath'

this is the full code

```
override open func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    guard let animator = dynamicAnimator else {
        return super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
    }

    return animator.items(in: rect) as? [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
}

override open func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    guard let indexPath = indexPath else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let animator = dynamicAnimator else {
        return super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
    }

    return animator.layoutAttributesForCell(at: indexPath) ?? setupAttributesForIndexPath(indexPath)
}

override open func prepare(forCollectionViewUpdates updateItems: [UICollectionViewUpdateItem]) {
    super.prepare(forCollectionViewUpdates: updateItems)

    updateItems.filter { $0.updateAction == .insert && layoutAttributesForItem(at: $0.indexPathAfterUpdate!) == nil } .forEach {
        setupAttributesForIndexPath($0.indexPathAfterUpdate)
    }
}
```

Do you guys have a solution for this?

Comment: What is the point of `guard let indexPath = indexPath else {
        return nil
    }`? indexPath isn't an optional

Answer (score 3):

indexPath is not optional so there is no need for guard